# Trivial edits that are not trivial

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, trivial

I recently came a across and answer that was overall a good answer. The only problem was that the answer was missing a newline in-between some text and a code block causing an entire block of code to be formatted incorrectly.I attempted to edit, but since the only thing I saw worth editing was that one newline, I could not edit it because of the six character minimum. I can see why SO wants to lower the amount of trivial edits, but this edit seemed well... less trivial. In cases such as this, I see only two solutions:

- Comment to the user that he is missing that newline
- Forget about it all together

What should I do when I see issues like the in a SO post?

Comment: Cheat and add an HTML comment `<!-- fixing code formatting -->` ;) Or wait until you have 2K rep...

Comment: That seems like great time to comment.

Comment: When I faced this situation it made me determined to reach 10k asap. :P

Answer (score 3):

The argument that there's always something else to fix is nonsense.

Sometimes there is just one glaring issue and the rest is fine and doesn't need editing.

In those cases you could consider adding a non visible `&nbsp;` and indicate in the edit summary something along the lines of

> Fixed issue with formatting. Non visible padding to meet minimum
>   length requirement.

IMO this complete block on submitting such edits on basis of an arbitrary character count should be removed, and perhaps replaced with a warning that the edit does not appear very substantive and there may be other issues to address. But which ultimately allows the edit to be submitted anyway.

Comment: Well, such small edits should be easier to reject then, maybe needing one reject less, as *most* will be really trivial despite the warning. They are probably great for doing a "reject and edit" though. Anyway, if you really want to propose that, find or post such a FR.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options.

- **Comment on the post.** Since you can't suggest an edit that would *only* fix that, then inform the poster that their formatting's off.  Who knows, someone with 2K+ rep may come along, see that message too and fix it.
- **Edit the post anyway.**  The likelihood of that being the *only* improvement with the post is slim, and if you see an opportunity to improve the question (phrasing, sentence structure, grammar, etc), then take it.  You can also fix the indentation issue while you're there as well, in a suggested edit.